# How to change color of an image in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i want to change color  in Illustrator link photoshop by using appearance (add new fill) but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Only the colors of vectors can be changed easily in illustrator.
A linked image has only the proporties of width, height, transparency and position.
Colors of embedded images might be changed with a plugIn from ASTUTE Phantasm: [Link to the PlugIn from ASTUTE](https://astutegraphics.com/software/phantasm/)
With the plugIn installed the values of the recoloring can be changed in the appearance panel so it's an undestructive way.

Linked images can be altered using Photoshop too. Embedded Images can also be unembedded and edited in Photoshop and afterwards linked again. (Adobe CC 2017).
For a group of vectors this should be interessting:

[image]